# What is the verb in "I go to school at 8:30."?

Tags: verbs, present-simple

Subject + Verb + Complement.

> I go to school at 8:30.

**What is the verb?** - "go to school" or "go"?

Comment: Can you explain why you think "to school" is part of the verb?

Comment: Are you asking because *to school* and *at 8:30* both seem to fit your pattern? Only one of those two is a complement, and it's not *at 8:30*.

Comment: "Go to school" wouldn't be the verb. However, conceivably, a phrase like "go to" could function as a [phrasal verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/phrasal-verbs). But that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"go" is the verb, (in simple present- implying a habit); "to school" is part of the predicate referring to **the place** you are going to and "at 8:30" is the rest of the predicate giving the information about **the time** when you do the activity.

Answer (score 1):

A sentence is made up of a subject, a predicate, and sometimes other words.  Sometimes, the subject is implied and is not given explicitly.  The predicate is a verb.  Any sentence can be condensed to just the subject and the predicate.  Your sentence could be condensed like this:

> I go.

It is not at all specific, so we expand on that and say where you go:

> I go *to school*.

Don't be confused by *to*.  It is not meant to be part of an infinitive.  It is a preposition that connects *go* to *school* because you can't just say "I go school."

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation for why my answer deserves a downvote.  I can't fix a problem if I don't know what it is ...